# get more fields from jsp page and save in DB

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp page with servlet.

- I want to get more than 400 fields from the single user and save them in the DB.
- User can modify the field values.

Are there any tools like GWT which can help me?

Comment: Personally I feel that 12 fields is excessive...why on Earth would you need 400?

Comment: thanks for the comment makoto, its the form for school, user have to fill their student list ,

Comment: i used getAttribute() for all fields, but its not possible to get all those fields ..

Comment: This is foolishness.. still I would say .. create a bean with 400 field(wow) and use Apache's BeanUtils to populate those fields. But who will enter those fields, User, I dont think so...

Comment: This should not be a programming problem because,if you or the school management needs the students to fill those forms you people need to figure out a way to reduce those fields to atleast 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can update fields "on change" through ajax call or you could try to use `getAttributeNames()` in servlet.